# How to set the widht of tooltip in dojo?

Tags: dojo, dijit.layout

I am using a tooltip (dijit.showTooltip) and sending the following parameters,

```
dijit.showTooltip('msg to be displayed', id);
```

Since, the "msg to be displayed" sometimes exceeds more than 500 character, its not shown in tooltip. Its going out of the screen :), so how can I set the width of the tooltip.

Answer (score 0):

The dijit.Tooltip will set its own width based on its contents. You can try to position the tooltip to an area of the screen where there is enough space. For example if the area at the left of the node is too small you can position the node above or below the node:

```
dijit.showTooltip('msg to be displayed', id, [“above”, “below”]);
```

Another thing you can try is insert line breaks at your message so that you control its width. The contents of the tooltip can be HTML instead of just plain text:

```
dijit.showTooltip('msg to be<br>displayed', id);
```

**UPDATE**:

Or if you want to let the browser arrange the text something like:

```
dijit.showTooltip('<div style="width: 50px">msg to be displayed</div>', id);
```